Why are the categories of category theory called "category"?
The category-theoretical concept called "category" seems quite dissimilar to what we consider a "category" in everyday life or colloquial speech and even other fields of science, where the term usually refers to a class in a categorization / classification, or more generally, of a taxonomy. So what was the motivation to use "category" as the term for that central concept of category theory?
I'm currently reading the book «The Joy of Abstraction — An Exploration of Math, Category Theory, and Life» by Eugenia Cheng, and have just finished that book's "Part one: Building up to categories" that ends with a chapter introducing the definition of a category as well as category diagrams inkl. commutative diagrams. I do think I understand (among others, from the previous chapters) the motivation for the concept of a "category" as defined there, and I also believe I understand that concept and its definition itself.
What's still missing to me though is the motivation for why it was named "category".
Are there some important similarities or analogies to our everyday notion of categories that I'm missing? Or did that term make more sense in the context of the sub-fields of mathematics that originally motivated the development of category theory? (Did the term maybe fit in nicely in some way or sense with other mathematical terms borrowed from everyday speech, such as "group" and "ring"?)

Note that at least since Aristotle, then the scholastics, and then Kant, "categories" have been a big talking point in philosophy with various different but related definitions.

@torsten-schoeneberg Defnitions "different but related" from/to what? From/to each other? From/to the category definition of category theory? From/to the everyday notion of categories?

Each other, and the everyday notion.

S.MacLane (Categories for the working mathematician, 1971, page 30): "The discovery of ideas as general as these is chiefly the willingness to make a brash or speculative abstraction, in this case supported by the pleasure of purloining words from the philosophers: “Category” from Aristotle and Kant, “Functor” from Carnap (logische Syntax der Sprache), and “natural transformation” from then current informal parlance."

See also John L. Bell, Reflections on Bourbaki’s Notion of “Structure” and Categories, into Alberto Peruzzi & Silvano Zipoli Caiani (editors), Structures Mères: Semantics, Mathematics, and Cognitive Science (2020, Springer) for the evolution of the concept of structure into that of species (that has been described by Pierre Cartier, a later Bourbaki member, as “a monstrous endeavor to formulate categories without categories”.) [Note again the Aristotleian term.] 1/2

And see para.2 Category Theory as a Theory of Mathematical Structure and Form: "The recognition that categories would have to incorporate as basic constituents not just structures but morphisms marks the fundamental advance of the category concept over Bourbaki’s idea of species." 2/2

Here is Saunders Mac Lane's own explanation of why he and Eilenberg chose the words "category", "functor" and "natural transformation":

A direct treatment of categories in their own right appeared in Eilenberg–Mac Lane [1945].   Now the discovery of ideas as general as these is chiefly the willingness to make a brash or speculative abstraction, in this case supported by the pleasure of purloining words from the philosophers: “Category” from Aristotle and Kant, “Functor” from Carnap (Logische Syntax der Sprache), and “natural transformation” from then current informal parlance.

This is from the notes at the end of Chapter I of Mac Lane's famous book Categories for the Working Mathematician.  (Both the 1971 and 1990 editions have this.)

This is interesting and relevant, but it’s not clear to me that it’s giving the main motivation for the word “category”.  I’ve always understood that as being simply the direct suitability of the word for the original motivating examples (as described in Mark Foskey’s answer), taken as too obvious to need mentioning, and then this quote as pointing out the wink to philosophy as a side benefit.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine The problem here is the difference between historical account of motivation and post-hoc meaningfulness to us, that for us motivates a concept. Given that this is HoSM I think we have to be clear about the distinction. I find Mark's explanation interesting, but we have (as best I know) no evidence that Eilenberg & Mac Lane followed that line of reasoning.

@GeorgEssl: I take your caution, but my point is a caution the other way as well: we shouldn’t over-interpret evidence just because it’s the only written evidence we’ve found.  What Mac Lane says here is that the discovery of category theory was “supported by the pleasure of purloining words from the philosophers” — which is not at all saying that these are the primary (let alone sole) reasons for choosing those names.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I wish we had some documentation about Eilenberg and Mac Lane discussing their coinage. I am sure it would be fascinating. Did they consider other terms? Which? Why? What was their motivation to settle on the coinage they did. Mac Lane's comment in CfWM gives only a very high level motivation. But without any evidence we have to call all of this speculation. I'm not saying that these speculations have no value. They do. But it's not history.

@GeorgEssl: Good history involves taking all the available evidence, and reconstructing a coherent picture, partly confident, partly tentative. If you find metal spearheads in an ancient battle site, you usually posit that there were originally also wooden shafts which have since rotted: you combine your material evidence with your knowledge of how spears usually worked, which is itself based on material evidence from other sites (among other things).  It’s certainly important to be clear which parts are more directly evidenced — but dismissing everything else as “not history” is bad history.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine If you read carefully I don’t advocate for dismissing anything. But I do advocate for care and being clear what is historically founded. I stand by this point. As for the rest I’d be happy to have a chat. I don’t think this is a complicated matter to resolve but not really fitting to a comment exchange.

It will probably be difficult to find documentation of Eilenberg and Mac Lane's thinking (added later - perhaps not as difficult as I thought!), but I would argue that a category does, in fact, capture the notion of a class in a taxonomy. If you were to categorize (in the everyday language sense) the objects of study in advanced mathematics, you might come up with groups, rings, fields, topological spaces, and so on. And those (together with their characteristic maps) are all categories in the category-theoretic sense of the term. So it seems wholly natural to me.

I think this is absolutely on the money, but I’d strengthen the last sentence: not only do groups, rings, spaces, etc all form categories, but moreover, these were the original motivating examples of categories for Eilenberg and Mac Lane.

According to Mathword

The term category was introduced by Samuel Eilenberg; Saunders MacLane "General Theory of Natural Equivalences," Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 58, No. 2. (Sep., 1945), pp. 231-294.  See the entries in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics and the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.


That answers the when and who, but not the why of that name choice. Though it points to https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory, where section 2. Brief Historical Sketch seems to give an important pointer: «[…] they [Eilenberg & Mac Lane] borrowed the word ‘category’ from the philosophy of Aristotle, Kant, and C. S. Peirce, but redefining it mathematically.»

(So I guess to answer my question, I'll have to dig into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category#Philosophy, which I previously believed to be unrelated to the mathematical term.)

In addition to the form extressed by Mac Lane in his Categories for the Working Mathematician (1971) as pointed out by Baez there is a similar later explanation found in:

Mac Lane, S. (1996). The development and prospects for category
theory. Applied Categorical Structures, 4, p.131:


There was also some fun with the choice of terminology. Since the
philosopher Kant had made ample use of general categories, the term
was borrowed from him for its present mathematical use, while Carnap,
in his book on Die Logische Syntax der Sprachen had talked of functors
in a different sense and made some corresponding mistakes. It seemed
in order to take over that word for a better and less philosophical
purpose.

An interesting though challenging perspective of the emergence of the use of the word "category" in Eilenberg-Mac Lane can be found in:

Krömer, R. (2007). Tool and object: a history and philosophy of
category theory (Vol. 32). Springer.

But the source is interesting also beyond the narrow scope as it identifies word usage outside the articulated history mainly by Mac Lane.
In the section titled "Reviewing the folklore history" he writes:

As indicated at the end of section 2.3.2.1, Eilenberg and Mac Lane
underestimated the achievements to be expected from their theory.
Anybody who is uncomfortable with that idea has probably in his turn a
too generous idea of what in [1945] really was achieved. Such an idea
can easily be adopted if one does not rely on the original work but
exclusively on the historiography of the protagonists, whose
unreliability shall be exemplified here again (see also 2.2.3).

This is indeed a serious matter. Who are we to question the presentation of the originators? However, this is the value of careful historiography and I do recommend reading Krömer arguments broadly as they are at minimum careful and interesting, even if one disagrees with some of his conclusions.
I personally am not of the view that there is a need to discard or disbelieve Mac Lane's account as I will argue below. A main source of confusion is that Mac Lane's description of the coinage in Categories for the Working Mathematician does not cleanly distinguish the two papers of 1942, which actually document an evolution of terms.
Mac Lane would describe this as follows (Categories for the Working Mathematician (henceforth CftWM) 1998 edition, p. 29):

Categories, functors, and natural transformations themselves were
discovered by Eilenberg-Mac Lane [1942a] in their study of limits (via
natural transformations) for universal coefficient theorems in tech
cohomology. In this paper commutative diagrams appeared in print (probably for the first time). Thus Ext was one of the first functors considered.

The citation refers to:

Eilenberg, S., & MacLane, S. (1942). Group extensions and homology.
Annals of Mathematics, 43(4), 757-831.

The first commutative diagram appears on page 777. However, neither the word functor nor the word category are used, but a notion of "naturality" is emphasized.
This changes very soon in their second paper of 1942:

Eilenberg, S., & MacLane, S. (1942). Natural isomorphisms in group
theory. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 28(12),
537-543.

Here the word "functor" and its content are defined for the first time (p.538). Also notice that "natural isomorphism" made it into the paper title hence is elevated as the central concept. It is defined in a categorical sense with the now famous commutative diagram (p.541) The word category does not appear. Hence in some sense all the pieces have indeed percolated by the second paper of 1942 and the language is essentially there except coining the concept of a "category"!
The famous paper of 1945 does contain the definition of category but the title is noteworthy as it says "General Theory of Natural Equivalences". This indeed suggests that the program from the first paper of 1942 was to grapple with the concept of naturality and explain it.
Some light about the perception of the paper by Eilenberg can be found in Mac Lane's autobiography:

Mac Lane, S. (2005). Saunders Mac Lane: a mathematical autobiography.
AK Peters/CRC Press.

where he writes (p. 209):

In 1945, when Sammy and I succeeded in publishing our systematic paper
on categories, "The General Theory of Natural Equivalences," Sammy
announced that this would be the only paper necessary on the subject.
It turned out that he was wrong. Probably, he had just the first use
of categories in axiomatized homology theory in mind, but later, more
general concepts about categories were developed and applied.

This really does suggest that for Eilenberg at least the paper was about closing the matter of naturality being not precisely understood and they had proposed a solution. Hence a paper that closes the matter. Of course this is in contrast to the the paper itself talking about this work being a generalized Erlangen program, which suggests a programmatic opening up of the topic. These contradictions are another part of the confusion in the very early history of category theory. Mac Lane indeed would proceed to advance ideas about category theory shortly after (1948) but Eilenberg's work would focus on crystalizing the ideas with respect to foundations of algebraic topology and later homological algebra. So perhaps the confusion could be attributed in different perspectives of the authors?
Yet regardless of the split in their 1945 paper they go into quite some pain to distance the proposed ideas as a foundational theory (p. 246):


Foundations. We remarked in §3 that such examples as the "category of all sets," the "category of all groups" are illegitimate. The difficulties and antinomies here involved are exactly those of
ordinary intuitive Mengenlehre; no essentially new paradoxes are
apparently involved. Any rigorous foundation capable of supporting the
ordinary theory of classes would equally well support our theory.
Hence we have chosen to adopt the intuitive standpoint, leaving the
reader free to insert whatever type of logical foundation (or absence
thereof) he may prefer.


They also describe the notion of a category as auxiliary (p. 247):

It should be observed first that the whole concept of a category is
essentially an auxiliary one; our basic concepts are essentially those
of a functor and of a natural transformation [..]. The idea of a
category is required only by the precept that every function should
have a definite class as domain and a definite class as range, for the
categories are provided as the domains and ranges of functors. Thus
one could drop the category concept altogether and adopt an even more
intuitive standpoint, in which a functor such as "Hom" is not defined
over the category of "all" groups, but for each particular pair of
groups which may be given. The standpoint would suffice for the
applications, inasmuch as none of our developments will involve
elaborate constructions on the categories themselves.

In many ways this gives quite a confusing picture, where categories evidently are shown to have interesting properties and structural value by many applications, yet there is a lack of commitment to them as well. Certainly they are not depicted as the central object of interest from which the whole body of ideas spring. Rather, as the saying goes one merely needs categories to define functors to define natural transformations.
In fact "category theory" as a subject itself is a process of percolation and development.
The following developments give an indication of rapid transformation of category theory from 1952-1958.
An oft-cited paper of advancing category theory is Grothendieck's Tohoku paper, while in terms of intellectual content often dated 1955:

Grothendieck, A. (1957). Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique.
Tohoku Mathematical Journal, Second Series, 9(2), 119-183. (english translation)

The following remarks by Mac Lane's following comment:

In 1954, I was invited to attend one of the private meetings of
Bourbaki, perhaps with the prospect that I could help to introduce
some category theory there.

Relevant discussions on this matter can be found here.
Category theory as structure theory was essentially proposed in writing by Ehresmann, though there is reason to believe that there was a multitude of discussion preceeding it.

Ehresmann, C. (1958). Gattungen von lokalen Strukturen. Jahresbericht
der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung, 60, 49-77.

This recognition of Ehresmann as structure theorist can be found in:

Pierre Ageron (2009) On Charles Ehresmann’s work: influences and
interactions. In Krömer, R., McLarty, C., & Wright, M. (2009).
Mini-workshop: Category theory and related fields: History and
prospects. Oberwolfach Reports, 6(1), 467-469.

Though certainly Mac Lane had interest in structural ideas as early as his dissertation work (see Lane, S. M. (1935). A logical analysis of mathematical structure. The Monist, 118-130.)
An indication that "category theory" as a field appears is also shown by the appearance of expositions exclusive to the topic (and no longer in connection to algebraic topology, group theory and so forth).
Perhaps the first work in category theory distinctly outside the scope of work in the nexus of algebraic geometry and topological groups is Nerode's thesis of 1956:

Nerode, A. (1956) Composita, Equations, and Recursive Definitions,
Dissertation, University of Chicago.

Just how much the idea of category theory had percolated is indicated by work by Rosen of 1958, which is likely the first applied category theory paper (McLarty indicates that this paper may be the first time the phrase "category theory" appears):

Rosen, R. (1958). The representation of biological systems from the
standpoint of the theory of categories. The bulletin of mathematical
biophysics, 20, 317-341.

Hence category theory is now a topic and could stand on its own. The first exposition that describes category theory as indeed its own topic is the review article:

Kurosh, A. G. E., Livshits, A. K., & Shul'geifer, E. G. E. (1960).
Foundations of the theory of categories. Russian Mathematical
Surveys, 15(6), 1.

For comparison Eilenberg and Steenrod's Foundations of Algebraic Topology dates 1952, and H. Cartan and Eilenberg Homological Algebra is 1956.
And the first book length exposition of category theory appears to be:

Mitchell, B. (1965). Theory of categories. Academic Press.

And category theory would be turned into a foundational theory with Lawvere's thesis of 1963. What happens between 1942/45 and 1963 is that the notion of naturality rapidly loses its central standing, and categories rapidly rise.
So by the time CfWM appears in 1971, the topic has gone through a substantial transformation and has become a theory and field of study in its own, quite different from 1945. This is important because the word category has completely changed its weight and and place in the theory. Rather than being a shallow auxiliary concept it has moved into the center and is really described as such by Mac Lane in it.
Mac Lane's description of the origins of the terms then is certainly up to some analysis in texts and this is what is attempted in Krömer.
Krömer (2.3.4.2 “Category” p. 74) shows that Lefschetz had already used the word "category of compacta" in 1942, but more interestingly traces a connection to Weil's book of 1940 on integration on topological groups where one finds the phrase "deux catégories de groupes" which Krömer argues is essentially categorical in Eilenberg-Mac Lane's sense and shows that indeed in 1942 Eilenberg-Mac Lane indeed references the section containing this very passage.
Certainly there is little question that Mac Lane's continued interest in duality (see his papers of 1948, which again cite the same book by Weil).
From this Krömer arrives at the theory that perhaps the term "category" might have come from "informal parlance" too. Krömer ends up saying:

Mac Lane wants us to believe that they were inspired by the
philosophical uses of the term <#4 p.69>; I think that the truth
rather is that both these philosophical definitions and their
mathematical concept are inspired by the common language use of the
term. (my note: #4 refers to CftWM)

I personally would not follow Krömer completely down this road, but certainly his traces of term usage are interesting and provide at least plausible explanation models.
Regardless, it is quite possible that Mac Lane was inspired by at least the verbage having come up in discussion of Kantian philosophy. As documented by McLarty:

McLarty, C. (2007). The last mathematician from Hilbert's Göttingen: Saunders mac lane as philosopher of mathematics. The British journal for the philosophy of science.

Who writes:

Mac Lane's doctoral study included Geiger's mathematics and an examination by Geiger Metaphysics [..] Geiger describes the relation between reality science, and reality as metaphysics strives with a Kantian perspective but without accepting Kant's critical solution [..]

It stands in no clear contradiction to Eilenberg and Mac Lane also having picked up the language in related usage in Lefschetz and Weil, following Krömer. Perhaps it is indeed both?
With all this said, how strong an association we ascribe to mention of Kant and Aristotle in the coinage of the now standard mathematical notion of a category may perhaps forever remain our own.
P.S. Further book length histories of categories or related matters are:

Marquis, J. P. (2008). From a geometrical point of view: A study of
the history and philosophy of category theory (Vol. 14). Springer.
Reck, E. H., & Schiemer, G. (Eds.). (2020). The prehistory of
mathematical structuralism. Oxford University Press.

P.P.S. Find further related discussion of interest here.

Also note the extensive use and definition of the word "categorical" in Veblen (1904) "A system of Axioms for Geometry" Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 5, p. 343-384.

Note the definition and use of the word "Kategorizität" (categoricity) and "kategorisch" (categorical) in von Neumann (1925) p.238, citing Veblen (1904) for introducing the notion.

According to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (emphasis mine):

Categories, functors, natural transformations, limits and colimits appeared almost out of nowhere in a paper by Eilenberg & Mac Lane (1945) entitled “General Theory of Natural Equivalences.” We say “almost,” because their earlier paper (1942) contains specific functors and natural transformations at work, limited to groups. A desire to clarify and abstract their 1942 results led Eilenberg & Mac Lane to devise category theory. The central notion at the time, as their title indicates, was that of natural transformation. In order to give a general definition of the latter, they defined functor, borrowing the term from Carnap, and in order to define functor, they borrowed the word ‘category’ from the philosophy of Aristotle, Kant, and C. S. Peirce, but redefining it mathematically.

(Edit: sorry, I didn't read das-g's comment which is very similar to this before posting my answer.)

I think it is important to distinguish between Eilenberg & Mac Lane's motivation for which we'd want a primary source, and a narrative as presented on SEoP which does not provide a citation to a primary statement by Eilenberg or Mac Lane about their motivation of the coinage. Without that primary source we cannot know if it is the writer of that SEoP article's view or E&M's view. Neither their 1942 nor their 1945 provides any basis for the claim about borrowing the terms.

I agree. The writer of that SEoP article didn't quote any source. We can imagine that Eilenberg & MacLane told some people about that but didn't write it. I don't know.

Baez's answer has answered my concern here. SEoP should have cited Mac Lane and removed the problem.
